# What is Injectable in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am studying NestJS, here is  my simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

const userMock = [{ account: 'dung', password: '12345678' }];

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  getUser() {
    return userMock
  }
}
```

I not really understand `@Injectable` in NestJS. Some tutorial tell `@Injectable` tell the `@Controller` know it's an install and can use it as a Dependency Injection. But when I remove it, it's still working.

Please give an example about difference between `@Injectable` and without `@Injectable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Injectable()` annotation allows you to inject instances.

Of course, that instance should have an @Injectible() annotation.

Let me show you an example.

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
  getName() {
    return 'ninezero90hy';
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private readonly personService: PersonService) {
    Logger.log(this.personService.getName())
  }
}
```

print 'ninezero90hy'

--

If there is no AppService or PersonService `@Injectible()` annotation, an error occurs.

--

Using the @Injectible() annotation

You can define the injection range.

This means that the nestjs container creates an instance.

--

Reference:

```
export declare enum Scope {
    /**
     * The provider can be shared across multiple classes. The provider lifetime
     * is strictly tied to the application lifecycle. Once the application has
     * bootstrapped, all providers have been instantiated.
     */
    DEFAULT = 0,
    /**
     * A new private instance of the provider is instantiated for every use
     */
    TRANSIENT = 1,
    /**
     * A new instance is instantiated for each request processing pipeline
     */
    REQUEST = 2
}
```

If you don't use `@Injectible()` annotations, nestjs doesn't manage instances, so an error will occur in the DI process.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLXMB.jpg)

Comment: This answer is not correct.
PersonService does not need the @Injectable annotation in the example.

Comment: This answer is wrong, @Injectable is only use if your class depends on other providers. It is used so that nestjs can build the dependencies tree in run-time

Answer (score 29):

`@Injectable()` is how you tell Nest this is a class that *can* have dependencies that should be instantiated by Nest and its DI system. The code you posted works because there are no injected dependencies. If, instead, you had

```js
const userMock = [{ account: 'dung', password: '12345678' }];

export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly otherService: OtherService) {}
  getUser() {
    return userMock
  }
}
```

`OtherService` would come back `undefined` due to `UserService` not being `@Injectable()`

Comment: As I understand, if we have @Injectable, it tell NestJS know that class can use other service of other module. Right?

Comment: I tried import a module has been initial in module, but when remove `@Injectable` in service, still error. It's mean if we want to user other class I have to init `@Injectable`. It's correct ???

Comment: How then do you explain this, "Decorator that marks a class as a provider. Providers can be injected into other classes via constructor parameter injection using Nest's built-in Dependency Injection (DI) system."?

Comment: @PromiseIhunna honestly, that's the easy answer for those who don't know how Typescript and metadata reflection works. I'll be working on adding an advanced page to the docs that kind of get more into the meat of what the decorators really do.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I think I understand now, please let me know when that is ready, thanks.

Comment: @Jay McDoniel I think this "Decorator that marks a class as a provider. Providers can be injected into other classes via constructor parameter injection using Nest's built-in Dependency Injection (DI) system." misguides the readers since it gives a totally different meaning.

Comment: If A is used by B ( A -> B). `@Injectable` according to this text, should be applied to A. Then it makes A "injectable" into B. But in reality, `@Injectble` to be applied to B to allow the DI container to detect it should resolve an instance of A to provide to B.

Answer (score 4):

With Nest.js' injector system, you can manage your objects without thinking
about the instantiation of them, because that is already managed by the injector, which is there to resolve the dependencies of every dependent object. With dependency injection, we connect different classes inside a module.

Let's say you have User Service:

```
export class UserService() {
 private users: Array<User> = [{
    id: 1,
    email: 'user@email.com',
    password: 'kjkjkj'
 ]};
 findOne(id:number): Promise<User> { 
    // should be `return this.repo.findOne(id)` but I dont wanna get into repository
 return  "write logic to return user"
 }
}
```

then let's say we have Authentication Service:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
   public userService: UserService;
   constructor() {
       this.userService = new UserService();
   }
 async validateAUser(payload: { email: string; password: string }):
     // Write logic
}
```

As you see, you have to manage all of the related dependencies in the class
itself to be used inside the AuthenticationService. The disadvantage of this is mostly the inflexibility of the AuthenticationService.If you want to test this service, you have to think about its own hidden
dependencies, and of course, you can’t share any services between different
classes.

Let's say you want to add another dependency into Authentication service or maybe you want to inject a different service. Then you need to create another instance of AuthenticationService. But using dependecy we can change the dependencies at run time rather than compile time because dependencies can be injected at run time